# Can't deploy a function to firebase because "admin.databse is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I tried to deploy this function to firebase:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref = admin.databse().ref();

exports.creatUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreat(event =>{
    const uid = event.data.uid;
    const newUserRef = ref.child('/users/${uid}');
    return newUserRef.set({
        uid: uid
    });
});
```

But Node.js threw me this: "admin.databse is not a function". What should I do?

Comment: maybe database instead of databse?

Comment: Oh man! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, `admin.databse().ref();` needs to be `admin.database().ref();`

Answer (score 0):

`database()` is instance's function.
So you should use as below.

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref = admin.databse().ref();
```

to =>

```
var instance = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref = instance.database().ref();
```